# Define "Macron below" / combining low line (U+0332) as a unicode character to underline text

Tags: unicode, newunicodechar

Consider the following (compile with xelatex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[verbose]{newunicodechar}

% List of symbols supported by Symbola at
% https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/symbola/list.htm
\newfontfamily\sym{Symbola}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\symb}{\sym}

\newunicodechar{}{\symb } % U+1F393, "Graduation Cap"
\newunicodechar{͟}{\symb ͟} % U+035F
% it would be nicer to use U+0332 ◌̲ COMBINING LOW LINE but I wasn't able to make it work.
% could also try with U+005.

\begin{document}
    
    
T͟h͟i͟s͟ ͟i͟s͟ ͟u͟n͟d͟e͟r͟l͟i͟n͟e͟d͟
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Obviously, the underlining is not very pretty, and I'm pretty sure that I could get better results using the unicode [U+0332](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0332) (◌̲ COMBINING LOW LINE) or [U+005F](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+005F) (_ LOW LINE), but couldn't make them work with `newunicodechar`.

What am I missing?

Comment: you need the font to support combining characters so don't use newunicodechar or do a font change for the combining character

Comment: Not sure what you miss, except that there are packages that do underlining. Do you want to use this approach for some specific reason?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Symbola supports both U+0332 and U+005F, so I _should_ be good. But how do you declare a combining character, I guess that's what I'm missing.

Comment: @mickep : I use a markdown ---> LaTeX ---> pdf approach (with pandoc), and markdown does not support underlining "natively". Hence, I'm trying to fake it with unicode characters.

Comment: @Clément you don't declare, just use the characters from your text font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+035F isn't widely supported, U+0332 is better supported, including by the default latin modern, although the result is not that pretty.

Note you  want support for combining characters in the font you are using for text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    
T̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲i̲s̲ ̲u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲d̲
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Unfortunately it is not supported by the Crimson font I am using (https://github.com/Fonthausen/CrimsonPro), but it's good to know that no additional manipulations are required to use this character. Thanks a lot!